# Connect to SOQL database via PHP

Tags: php, database, soql

I am extremely new to php and database. Suddenly I'm handed down this community service project where they want me to connect to a SOQL database, retrieve the data and display it on a page. 
Being a complete newbie to this, I've searched in google of how to connect to a soql database, but to no avail. I know for mysql I can establish a link/connection by running `mysql_connect(host, user, password)`; in a php. Is there a way to do something similar in `SOQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot connect to an SOQL database via PHP.

You can, however do it using JavaScript and then use ajax to receive PHP output based on the database.

Comment: I see, thank you. Could you provide me with some more information on how to connect to it using javascript? 
I found something like this: `var qr = sforce.connection.query("Select Name,Id From Contact ORDER BY Name") ;` But not entirely sure if this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provides web services API(REST) to connect its ecosystem.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject